# Make android app non erasable

Tags: android, android-intent

Is is possible to make an android app non deletable.. What i mean is, I want to install a app, but I cant remove/ uninstall it. If I want to uninstall it then it should prompt me for password which I would have set during installation of the app.

When I read the docs they tell it can be done using Device Admin, but it doesnt provide security, interms of it doesn't ask the user for the password and deletes if its correct..

Is it possible to make an app such that even if there is a factory reset the app will still be there on the phone ?

Comment: For app in Google Play, this is not possible.

Comment: why you want to do like so ..

Comment: i don't think its possible and also its not a legal practice..

Answer (score 2):

> Is is possible to make an android app non deletable

No, unless you want to create your own ROM and preload it with your app, just like some manufactures preload their devices with their own software and other bloatware.

Answer (score 0):

No it is possible to restrict any user to delete the app from android device.

As google already maintaining this scenario by using the concept known as Device Management System.

Google Eyeing on apps which are published by the developer / installed or deleted by the user.

Although you can make your own app which will notify your admin that user is trying to delete the app or deleted the app, using Service Intent concept.